# $http post gets canceled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

I have a login form and I'am trying to send a post request to server but it gets canceled.

Here is controller:

```
angular.module('app.signin', [])
.controller('SigninController', ['$http', function($http) 
{
    this.email      = null;
    this.password   = null;

    this.signIn = function()
    {
        var res = $http.post( 'http://api.svcassist.dev/index.php/auth/login', {email: this.email, password: this.password });

        res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
        {
                alert(data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

and here is html:

```
<div class="container" style="max-width:300px" ng-controller="SigninController as signin">
    <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus ng-model="signin.email">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required ng-model="signin.password">
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="signin.signIn()">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and Chrome says that request is canceled, here are the response headers:

```
Request URL:http://api.svcassist.dev/index.php/auth/login
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/app/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:6C7F2AA6-481A-32ED-0CFC-8F4B9F5927B8
Request Payloadview parsed
{"email":"email","password":"pass"}
```

Comment: Those are the request headers, please paste the response

Comment: There are no response headers sine request is canceled

Comment: The code that u post is insufficient.... There is no POST method to check what is bad... I would recommend to you , learn promise pattern http://blog.xebia.com/2014/02/23/promises-and-design-patterns-in-angularjs/

Comment: If you are using Angular, then why you assign model to this object in controller? And not use $scope instead? Secondly you are calling 'api.svcassist.dev' host, is it your application, or you want to make a cross-site call?

Comment: I'am new to Angular. Yes api.svcassist.dev is my application and CORS headers are in place.

Comment: Beri: he is using the 'as' syntax. His controller is in the scope, so his variables are as well.

Comment: If you watch the request with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), is the request listed there? You might find out more this way.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Is it specific to Chrome?

Comment: Try adding `type="button"` to your button.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ng-submit:

#### html

```
<div class="container" style="max-width:300px" ng-controller="SigninController as signin">
    <form ng-submit="signin.signIn(signin.email, signin.email)" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus ng-model="signin.email">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required ng-model="signin.password">
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### js

```
this.signIn = function(email, password)
{
    var res = $http.post( 'http://api.svcassist.dev/index.php/auth/login', {email: email, password: password });

    res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
    {
            alert(data);
    });
};
```